# Prototype bean injuected in a singleton bean

Tags: java, spring-boot

I defined a prototype bean named TestService,contains a string property,as follows:

```
@Service
@Scope(scopeName = BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE, proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS)
public class TestService {

    private String name = "hhh";
    public void test() {
        System.out.println(this.name);
        System.out.println("test");
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name.toString();
    }
}
```

then I injected the prototype bean into a singleton bean, defined as follows:

```
public class TestController {

    private final UserCenterFeign userCenterFeign;


    private TestService testService;

    @Lookup
    public TestService getTestService() {
        return testService;
    }

    @SentinelResource(value = "/test")
    @PostMapping("/test")
    public String test(String a) {
        System.out.println(testService);
        testService.setName(a);

        testService.test();
        return "test";
    }
}
```

when i invoke the TestController.test method ,the testService's property name remains null value,anyone who kows why?

Comment: because you are not creating object of thec lass TestService.

Comment: that is how you setup your beans: `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS` causes spring to create new bean instance for each method call.